# Customizer image control default value showing in customizer but not on frontend

Tags: customization, images, theme-customizer

I use the `WP_Customize_Image_Control` to add the image.

But, The `default` value is accessible in `Customizer` only!!! 
On front-end It return `empty`.

#### How to reproduce?

Copy below code snippet and paste in your themes `functions.php`.

Visit URL `http://YOUR_SITE/wp-admin/customize.php?autofocus[section]=section-test_option` to open section `Test Section`

```
add_action( 'customize_register', 'test_1234_customize_register' );
add_action( 'wp_head', 'test_1234_customizer_ouput_debug' );

function test_1234_customizer_ouput_debug() {

    // $options = get_theme_mod( 'this-is-the-test-option' );
    $options = get_option( 'this-is-the-test-option' );
    echo '<pre style="background: #fff;">Default Image URL: ';
    print_r( $options );
    echo '</pre>';
}

function test_1234_customize_register( $wp_customize ) {

    /**
     * Test Section
     */
    $wp_customize->add_section( 'section-test_option', array(
        'title' => __( 'Test Option', 'next' ),
    ) );

    /**
     * Test Option - 1
     */
    $wp_customize->add_setting( 'this-is-the-test-option', array(
        'default' => 'https://www.google.co.in/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png',
        'type'    => 'option',  // Comment this parameter to use 'get_theme_mod'
    ) );
    $wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Image_Control( $wp_customize, 'this-is-the-test-option', array(
        'section'        => 'section-test_option',
        'label'          => __( 'Test', 'next' ),
        'settings'       => 'this-is-the-test-option',
        'library_filter' => array( 'gif', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'ico' ),
    ) ) );
}
```

---

#### Output

1. In Customizer window preview

http://bsf.io/net4f

2. In Front End ( Checked in Incognito window too )

http://bsf.io/u59cm

---

As per above example I'm able to use:
`get_option( 'this-is-the-test-option', 'https://www.google.co.in/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png' )` to get default image.

But, It'll be fail if I store the options in array. E.g.

```
$wp_customize->add_setting( 'this-is-the-test-option[option1]', array(
...

$wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Image_Control( $wp_customize, 'this-is-the-test-option[option1]', array(
...
```

In above situation the best solution is merging the default values. I found the solution suggested by @westonruter in [gist](https://gist.github.com/westonruter/c9b9cf597e9e9129070d67b68920168e/9d9a4d8f0a751b549dff17c34f4790568316d8ac#file-functions-php-L37).

---

But, Questions are:

1. Why the default value is accessible in `Customizer Preview window`? ( As per the above code snippet.)
2. Is `default` parameter for the control `WP_Customize_Image_Control` is useful?

Answer (score 1):

The default value that you set on the image `add_setting` will only be applyed if there is a any option called 'reset to default' on the image control. This argument will not output any default value to the page.

The second argument of the function `get_option( 'option_name', $default )`. The `$default` parameter **will not submit anything to the DB**. It only returned if the option does not exists. e.g: when the user installed the theme, and the logo (or the option that displays anything on the page) must not be empty. But if he save the option, the option will exist on the db, even if empty. Then this default will not apply anymore. it works like a place holder.

If you want a default value, even if the option are saved and return a empty string, you can do this:

```
$option = get_option( 'option_name', $default )
echo ( empty( $option ) ? 'default' : $option );
```

The empty() function will check if the returned value are a empty string, or anything that represents a empty (boolean, integer, null, etc). You can read more here: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.empty.php

This way, a default value will be ever applyed, if the option exists.

> Note: its a best practice to use `'type' => 'theme_mod'` when creating mods for themes, not `'type' => 'option'`. If you omit this
>   arg, the default will be theme_mod.

Comment: I agree with you. It means that we need to set 2 default values? 1. In `add_setting` to retrieve the value in customizer preview only. and 2. In front end where we access it.

Comment: I notice that this is NOT related with `Customizer Image Control`. It's for all the customizer default values.

Comment: The default value on add_setting will not apply to all customizer controls, it will be only for the control that you assign to the respective setting.

Comment: Yes, I mean initially customizer does not store any default values of any setting in DB. In my e.g. I thought its `Image Control` issue.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Felipe for explanation & @westonruter for providing the solution in the [gist](https://gist.github.com/westonruter/c9b9cf597e9e9129070d67b68920168e/9d9a4d8f0a751b549dff17c34f4790568316d8ac#file-functions-php-L37).

Solution: Create `defaults` array and use it in *Customizer* & on *Front End*.

**Step-1:** Register theme defaults array.

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'my_theme_defaults' ) ) {

    function my_theme_defaults() {

        return array(
                    'option-1' => 1,
                    'option-2' => 'author',
                    'option-3' => '#3a3a3a',
                    'option-4' => 'ALL RIGHT RESERVED'
                    'option-5' => get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/images/logo-black.png'
                );
    }
}
```

---

**Setp-2**: Access in Customizer & FrontEnd.

#### Access in Customizer

```
//  Get theme default values
$theme_defaults = my_theme_defaults();

...
$wp_customize->add_setting( 'my-theme-options[option-1]', array(
    'default' => $theme_defaults['option-1'],
    ...
) );
...
$wp_customize->add_setting( 'my-theme-options[option-2]', array(
    'default' => $theme_defaults['option-2'],
    ...
) );
...
```

#### Access on Front End

```
//  Get theme stored values
// Note: I use the `'type' => 'option',` for all the options. So, Getting stored values of option 'my-theme-options' using `get_option()`. You can use `get_theme_mod()` if you use it for `add_settings()`.
$theme_stored   = get_option( 'my-theme-options' );

//  Get theme default values
$theme_defaults = my_theme_defaults();

//  Merge both
$theme_options = wp_parse_args( $theme_stored, $theme_defaults );

//  Access option value    
//  e.g.
echo $theme_options['option-1'];
echo $theme_options['option-2'];
echo $theme_options['option-3'];
```

---

**NOTE: Don't forget to use filters where ever possible to extend in future. Also, Add text translations.**

Answer (score 0):

Very easy solution, try it. Hope It will help you.

Simply use this code in your front-end.

**From your own directory-**

```
<img src="<?php echo esc_url(get_theme_mod('this-is-the-test-option',''.get_template_directory_uri().'/images/logo.png')); ?>" alt="Google"/>
```

**From online link-**

```
<img src="<?php echo esc_url(get_theme_mod('this-is-the-test-option','https://www.google.co.in/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png')); ?>" alt="Google"/>
```